# How do I compare two integers

Tags: python

```
limit_speed = 50
current_speed = int(input("speed now :"))
def displayPenalty(limit_speed, current_speed):
        if current_speed - limit_speed == 0:
            print("no charge")
        elif current_speed - limit_speed == 20:
            print("charge 20 dollars")
        elif current_speed - limit_speed == 40:
            print("charge 40 dollars")
```

How do I make this function work so that it will check the difference between the 2 integers and print out based on it?

Comment: what is the current problem? please explain.

Comment: please read this guide :)https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: You can simply do ```if current_speed>limit_speed: print(f"Charge {current_speed-limit_speed} dollars")```? Please see [ask]

Comment: i want to make a function named display penalty that accepts the 2 integers. and find the difference between the 2 integers so that it can check whether it surpass the speed limit or not

Answer (score 1):

I think this is what you are looking for:

```
limit_speed = 50
current_speed = int(input("speed now :"))
def displayPenalty(limit_speed, current_speed):
        if current_speed <= limit_speed:
            print("no charge")
        else:
           print(f'charge: {current_speed - limit_speed}')
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply check if one value is greater than the other. (I think you would want this)...

```
def displayPenalty(limit_speed, current_speed):
    if current_speed>limit_speed: print(f"Charge {current_speed-limit_speed} dollars")
    else: print("no charge")
```

Answer (score 0):

see below (I think this is what you are looking for)

```
limit_speed = 50


def displayPenalty(limit_speed, current_speed):
    delta = current_speed - limit_speed
    if delta == 0:
        print("no charge")
    elif 0 < delta <= 20:
        print("charge 20 dollars")
    elif 20 < delta:
        print("charge 40 dollars")


current_speed = int(input("speed now :"))
displayPenalty(limit_speed, current_speed)
```